# C++ Use "this" as a parameter?

Tags: c++, class, object, parameters

So, I'm trying to reproduce one thing I learned in Java in my C++ program and I just can't make this work!

Here's a example of what I want to do:

```
class Game{
public:
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    Screen* titleScreen;
    void createScreen(){
        titleScreen = new Screen(this);
    }
}

class Screen{
public:
    Game* game;
    Rect quad1;
    Screen(Game* game){
        this->game = game;
        quad1.x = game->screenWidth/2;
    }
}
```

I'm not even sure if this code is right because I created it right now just to show what I want to do.

So, basically, what I want to do is create a reference for "Game" inside "Screen" so I can use its atributes and methods(in this case, the screen width), even though "Screen" is being instantiated inside "Game". I did something like this in Java and it worked perfectly, but for C++ I get so many erros that I don't even know how to interpret them... I tried using pointer for the parameters and instead of using "this" I tried using "&this" but none of them worked and I get pratically the same errors...

So, what am I doing wrong? How can i make this work? Is this even possible in C++?

Comment: Your constructor takes the argument by value but you are passing it a pointer. Looks like you'll want to take the argument by reference as noted in your post.

Comment: If you want a reference, use a reference. `Screen(Game& game);` or better yet: `Screen(const Game& game);`

Comment: You should probably [**read this**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) while you're doing this. Something tells me you're going to be wondering why things crash when you add the destructor for `Game`

Comment: @WhozCraig: Or, with C++11, [The Rule of Zero](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/rule-of-zero)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious But, if I use `Game &game` I will only be able to use it as a reference only for that function(in this case, the constructor), no? But what if I want use the same reference in another function, one that `Game` doesn't call, but a totally different class who is using the same `Screen` object as `Game` calls? Or even if `Game` is the one calling the function, let's say I have a 100 methods in `Screen` and each one uses a 100 atributes from `Game`, I would have to pass every single atribute as a parameter for every single method?

Comment: In C++ a reference is simply an alias to an object and can be passed around and shared just like pointers. There is no reason why you can't take the object by reference and then pass that reference around when necessary - as long as you maintain clear ownership semantics. As a side note and IMHO `Screen` should not have knowledge of `Game` at all. The cyclic dependency creates an extremely tight coupling which is unnecessary.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious But how do I pass this reference to other methods? And if `Screen` doesn't have knowledge of `Game`, how am I supposed to gain access to its atributes and methods? For example, in my project `Game` does not only has the screen size, but also an input object, a renderer object(I'm using SDL2), a window object and some other things. `Game` acts like a place for "global" variables and objects, and it's the responsible for changing screens. Of, course, I wont need to use, like, the window object in many things, but the renderer is one thing that I'll use all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use a forward declaration and define the function after the definition of the things it needs.

```
class Screen; // Forward declaration

class Game{
public:
    int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    Screen * titleScreen;
    void createScreen();
}

class Screen{
public:
    Game* game;
    Rect quad1;
    Screen(Game *game){
        this->game = game;
        quad1.x = game->screenWidth/2;
    }
}

// Out-of-line definition.
// This should be declared "inline" if it's in a header file.
void Game::createScreen(){
    titleScreen = new Screen(this);
}
```

Comment: I'm declaring all the classes and its atributes/methods in a header file for each one and defining them in a .cpp file, so "Game.h" is including "Screen.h" and "Screen.h" is including "Game.h" (of course, all my headers has a "pragma once" on them).

Comment: @Deive_Ex `#include` works greedily whether you use `#pragma once` or not. Each header file will be opened by the compiler if it hasn't been opened yet. Circular dependencies are not resolved by the compiler; you need to follow this pattern to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

a)Make forward declaration of Game class.

b)Make `Screen(Game *game)` constructor to accept a pointer not an object since you are passing this pointer.

Refer following sample

http://ideone.com/J8He9f

Comment: Actually, I'm declaring all the classes and its atributes/methods in a header file for each one and defining them in a .cpp file, so "Game.h" is including "Screen.h" and "Screen.h" is including "Game.h" (of course, all my headers has a "pragma once" on them).
I tried using a pointer as a parameter, but I get the same errors(also, VS says I can't pass "this" if I'm using pointers)